# QLabel setText() doesn't work in Event() function in Qt environment

Tags: qt, settext, qlabel

there is a QLabel object named rightLabel in My Dialog, and when I click right button ,I want the rightLabel display "right Click OK.", but it doesn't work. Then the code is :

```
    bool MyDialog::event(QEvent *evt)
{
    if(evt->type()==QEvent::ContextMenu)
    {
        qDebug()<<"rightbutton";   //that's ok
        this->rightLabel->setText("Right Click OK");//doesn't work
    }
    ……
```

Answer (score 0):

You should `return QDialog::event(evt);` and all will be good.

```
bool MyDialog::event(QEvent *evt)
{
    if(evt->type()==QEvent::ContextMenu)
    {
        qDebug()<<"rightbutton";   //that's ok
        this->rightLabel->setText("Right Click OK");//will work
    }
    //other if
    return QDialog::event(evt);
}
```